# Installing Infinality

Tags: release-juno, fonts

Just moved to Elementary and installed Jetbrains IDE but my font looks very different compared to OSX.

I found the below instructions but trying to install it results in an error saying it can't be found.

How can I install it or get my fonts to look like they are on OSX?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:no1wantdthisname/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install fontconfig-infinality
```

Answer (score 1):

This Reddit thread may help provide some context to the problem:

[https://reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/5pcjsr/what_happened_to_infinality/](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/5pcjsr/what_happened_to_infinality/)

Answer (score 0):

To install a custom PPA in elementary OS, you need to install `software-properties-common`. Did you do that already? If not install `software-properties-common` and run the commands you named again.

Comment: It was already installed apparently. Running the commands above results in `Unable to locate package fontconfig-infinality`

Comment: For me it appears to be the same. It seems like it's not part of that PPA anymore since `Ubuntu Bionic`, but you could however download it manually from [here](https://launchpad.net/~no1wantdthisname/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages) and install it that way, not sure if that works though.