# font rendering in Hera

Tags: release-hera, fonts

I have a question about out-of-the-box font rendering in Hera.

As you can see in the screenshot below, letters don't look very good.

They don't look very smooth, seem to vary in their thickness.

Is this normal?

When I watched some reviews of Elementary OS on YouTube, their fonts looked a lot better than this.

If this is the default rendering, what can be done to make this situation better?

[image: image of EOS wiki page on my desktop]

[image]

Comment: I was surprised to find out that the same screenshot looked a lot better on my Macbook Pro and my Windows desktop. It still looks horrible on my elementary OS.
Especially, the rendering gets horrible on web browsers, namely, Ephiphany and Firefox. I still do believe that it has something to do with sub-pixel rendering. Something must not be working correctly for this kind of behavior to happen.

Comment: I encountered issues with Firefox and Microsoft fonts, particularly the rendering of Calibri in Outlook in Firefox. This may be caused by the same issue you encountered too? I searched for a solution and discovered a tool call Infinality which instantaneously made a difference. [This Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2385152) post contained a solution that I successfully followed. [This post in the Elementary OS Stack Exchange](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16830/installing-infinality) explores the use of the tool too. There are likely to be more grace

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't agree more that Elementary/Hera's default font rendering is very much sub-par, especially when compared with Apple devices (most notably iOS), and although it may not seem it, I believe this is actually a major issue for so many users interested in migrating, epecially from OSX. As per the comments above, I believe this is more involved than simply adjusting subpixel rendering settings, and something like fontconfig-infinality may indeed be needed, although it seems that may present significant problems, as it is no longer supported ([see the following reddit thread on the topic for more info](https://reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/5pcjsr/what_happened_to_infinality/)). Can this not be integrated into the default distribution of elementary, so as to avoid the need for going to these unbelievaly arduous lengths simply to get some decent font rendering in what is otherwise perhaps the most attractive viable open-source OSX-alternative?